# I don't get what is happening inside the while loop . Would you please explain?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    while (i++ != 0);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Output: `1`

I do not understand the `while` loop.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: `while(i++ != 0);` is the same as `while(i++ != 0) { /* void */ }` .... so the loop just increments `i` for ever and ever ... until it reaches its maximum and the program invokes Undefined Behaviour ... (or until it crosses over to the negatives and climbs all the way up to `0`)

Comment: the change of the sign will only happen, als long as you do not use unsigned data types (i.e. uint i=10)

Comment: thanks @pmg, I was little bit confused. Now it's okay.

Comment: @paul_schaefer , so if I use uint then it will become zero after reaching the maximum positive value

Comment: Right, no Undefined Behaviour with `unsigned` types. The Standard mandates that is works "mod (UINT_MAX + 1)"

Answer (score 0):

`i` is incremented until the `int` variable saturates (32767 when int is 16 bits long) and then starts counting up from -32.768 to zero. When `i` becomes zero, the while-loop stops. Because of the post increment `i++`, `i` will be one when the while loop is finished. So you get one as a result printed to your output.

**Edit: Long explanation:**
When executing the while condition the first time, it will be checked if 10 is not equal to 0. After this check, `i` is incremented to 11, next check is 11 not equal to zero, and `i` becomes 12. This continues until you reach the highest possible value for `int`. When this maximum value is incremented, you get the lowest possible value, but this is also not equal zero. So the condition is still true, but now you have a negative number, and a negative number incremented will get zero. So after some time, `i` becomes zero and the while condition is false and since `i` is incremented after this check, you will get an output of one.

Comment: *When increment this maximum value, you get the lowest possible value* I'm afraid this behavior is not guaranteed by the C Standard and the C compiler may determine that `i` is only incremented in the loop and starts at `10`, hence the loop never ends. This is what gcc does on [Godbolt's  Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/63MG6595x)

Comment: I'am aware of this problem but if the received output is 1 as written in the question, then there are two posibilities: The behaviour is as I assumed or the compiler removes the while-statement because it is empty and initializes i with one

Comment: Your answer does not hint that the observed behavior, for which your explanation is pertinent, is only a possibility, not the semantics of the C language which leaves this particular case undefined. The program may behave differently for many reasons, even with the same compiler (`-O0` vs `-O2` for example)... don't let the OP in the dark about undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The code has undefined behavior:

- the `while` loop has an empty body consisting of a null statement `;`.
- hence the loop iterates doing nothing more than the side effect in the test `i++ != 0`.
- `i` starts at `10` so the first test is true, `i` is incremented to `11` and the loop continues with the test again... `i` is incremented all the way to `INT_MAX`, which is a least `32767`, but more commonly `2147483647` and incrementing `i` with this value has a undefined behavior because it causes a signed arithmetic overflow. What happens then is undefined, the program could stop, run an infinite loop, turn the lights off... anything is possible.
- on your system, `i` will probably just get the value `INT_MIN` an no bad side effect will happen.
- the loop continues, incrementing `i` through all the negative values...
- until `i` finally becomes `0`, making the test evaluate to false and break the loop after the side effect of `++` happens for the last time, leaving `i` with the value `1`.
- the last statement `printf("%d",i);` prints `1`, without a newline, which may prevent the output from reaching the terminal on some legacy systems.

So depending on the system, the program can:

- print `1` and exit immediately
- print `1` after pause and exit
- run forever and print nothing<sup>*</sup>
- crash with some kind of error
- cause a more of less important side effect, such as summoning aliens from Sirius to invade planet Earth...

---

(*) `gcc -O2` compiles the posted code to a single `jmp` instruction on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/63MG6595x).

Comment: @sj95126: the empty `while()` body is not the issue, incrementing `i` beyond `INT_MAX` causes signed arithmetic overflow which has undefined behavior.